# Why do I get an empty file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to generate a template from helm chart and want to save the result into a file:

```
helm template dashboard -n dev --set image.tag=0.1.0 ./dashboard > ./test.yml
```

but I've got an empty file.

Runnning without to put the result into the file:

```
helm template dashboard -n dev --set image.tag=0.1.0 ./dashboard   

---
# Source: dashboard/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dashboard
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: dashboard-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: dashboard
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: dashboard
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.17.5"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
```

As you can see, it generates the output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your command, I tested on my lab running Debian (I'm using bash) and it worked as expected.

Comment: But, why it does not work on my computer. I am also using bash.

Comment: Please, try using `helm template dashboard -n dev --set image.tag=0.1.0 ./dashboard | tee test.yml`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an output directory, otherwise it will template to stdout

`helm template dashboard -n dev --set image.tag=0.1.0 ./dashboard --output-dir ./dashboard-hydrated`

Answer (score 0):

You also can use:

```
helm install dashboard -n dev --set image.tag=0.1.0 ./dashboard --dry-run --debug > your-output.yaml
```

The `--dry-run` will not deploy your helm chart directly.